# Small signal diagram for a PMOS

Tags: mosfet

What is the small signal diagram for a PMOS? Would it be the same as that of an NMOS but instead of \$I = g_m V_{sg}\$, for a PMOS we have to use \$I = g_m V_{gs}\$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small signal diagram would be the same just with polarities reversed, so you can write it as \$I = g_mV_{sg}\$. As long as you aware of polarities though, either way could be used.

[Here](http://www.prenhall.com/howe3/microelectronics/pdf_folder/lectures/mwf/lecture12.fm5.pdf#page=8) and [here](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee105/fa06/handouts/discussions/Small_Signal_Analysis.pdf) are reasonable documents with PMOS (and NMOS) small signal models and related equations (see first link, 8th page for diagram of both together)

Comment: By polarity, you mean the direction of the current source (the direction of the arrow), right?